# Auto-change comments in java classes

Tags: autocomplete, javadoc

Do you know any utility to change comments in java classes automatically? Also it's about updating copyright date in java classes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ANT Task to update source's text
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html